# Hermitian curves introductory references

Tags: resources, coding-theory, hermitian-curves

Could you give me some reference to start on Hermitian Curves. Some papers or textbooks would be perfect, and please mention if it's math inclined or comp.sci. inclined.

I've only seen hermitian curves in coding theory but if you know of applications of these curves to cryptography please let me know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Algebraic Geometry Codes: Basic Notions" by Tsfasman, Vladut, and Nogin is a textbook that is [available as a PDF](http://www.math.umass.edu/~hajir/m499c/tvn-book.pdf). Discussion of Hermitian curves begins on page 167.

I haven't read it and no very little about coding theory. It was the reference a friend provided in his dissertation, which included constructing universal hash functions from Hermitian curves.

Comment: Looks great. I was about to recommend Stichtenoth's book, but this seems to go much deeper.